# Problems with File in Lua

Tags: string, file, lua

I want know how to delete a specific file line ?

example : file.txt

1. facebook
2. twitter
3. orkut
4. msn

Suppose I want to delete the line 3 then the file would be :

1. facebook
2. twitter
3. msn

I do not want to just delete the lines, need to organize and avoid getting empty lines in the file!

Comment: Are line numbers part of text?

Comment: no! It was only to exemplify

Comment: read file content, `local n=0; text=text:gsub('.-\n',function() n=n+1 return n==3 and '' end)`, write result to file

Answer (score 1):

Load the file contents, manipulate them in memory, then write the new contents back to the file.

In this case you can load the file contents line by line using `files.lines`, store the ones you want in an array and leave out the ones you don't, then turn the array back into a string with `table.concat`.

Comment: You can show in an example? 

local file = io.open("termino.txt", "r")
 while true do
    line = file:read()

Answer (score 0):

## You could look for a specific item by matching a string:

```
function func(file, toDelete)
    local t = {}
    local tt = {}
    for line in io.lines(file) do
            table.insert(t, line)
    end

    for c, r in pairs(t) do
            if string.sub(r, 4) ~= toDelete then
                    table.insert(tt, string.sub(r, 4))
            end
    end

    local nfile = io.open(file, "w+")

    for a, b in pairs(tt) do
            nfile:write(a .. ". " .. b .. "\n")
    end
end
```

## or by looking for the number:

```
function func(file, num)
    local t = {}
    local tt = {}
    for line in io.lines(file) do
            table.insert(t, line)
    end

    for c, r in pairs(t) do
            if c ~= num then
                    table.insert(tt, string.sub(r, 4))
            end
    end

    local nfile = io.open(file, "w+")

    for a, b in pairs(tt) do
            nfile:write(a .. ". " .. b .. "\n")
    end
end
```

Carefull: this overrides the **original** file!

**EDIT:**
This is working for the example above, without the numbers in the front, you don't have to substitute the string.